# Save to Hard Drive instead of bootable USB

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, filesystem, live-usb

I followed the instructions on the Ubuntu website on how to put Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB and make it a bootable USB stick for windows.

It worked fine and I can boot up and run Ubuntu, but every time I try to download software or change settings it tries to save it to the USB rather than the hard drive built into the computer.

The USB doesn't have enough space so the download fails and in addition it doesn't retain setting changes so when I restart my computer all the settings return to default and anything I saved is gone.

Is there any way to change things so that when I download software or change settings Ubuntu will save it to my hard drive instead of the USB?

Comment: How are you downloading?

Comment: what is your usb size and what is the file you downloaded?

Comment: Mitch: I am downloading using the terminal.  Nick:I am trying to download a program called ROS and it is a 4GB flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
wget location of file/name of file -P ./LOCAL-DIR
```

Example, if you want to download file `stuff.deb` from `http://mysite.com,` and save it to `/home/user/download`, you would do

```
wget http://mysite.com/stuff.deb.exe -P ./home/user/download
```

Answer (score 0):

When the live USB is created with persistence, your settings should be saved from session to session.  With a 4G stick, you should be able to have a 3G persistence file to save anything of yours, and even some system parts.  UEFI machines have a problem with persistence (but 1159016) but you can manually fix it (see the bug).  Running from USB, you will be able to mount a hard disk partition, and write to it, but think about how you want to use the data you download.  Do you want to see it from the Windows OS also?  In that case, leave the filesystem on the mounted partition ntfs.  If you only want to use the data from Ubuntu, you may make the filesystem ext4.  Make a little script for the mount command.  The live USB persistence does not allow updates to the kernel, and fstab was another file that could not be changed (last time I looked).  If /etc/fstab could be successfully persisted, you could put the mount command there and have it automatically performed at startup.